# Forwarding an event to another element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a grid control in HTML/JS and I'd like it to behave as much as possible like Excel. I've got most of the navigation and editing done already but there's one thing I can't figure out and everything I've found online didn't work in my case.

First I'm going to explain a bit how I've implemented it:
I've made the grid using a table and inserted a textbox in each td. The textboxes do not get the focus unless you double click in the cell (much like in Excel). In other words, clicking a cell simply select it and you can edit it by double clicking. You can navigate around by using the arrow keys, this was done by attaching a keypress event handler on the document.

Now, when a cell is selected, I'd like to be able to start editing it simply by typing. To do this, I added some code in my event handler that controls the navigation that checks if the user is typing visible characters (e.charCode != 0) and set the focus in the textbox of the selected cell. That works fine except that the first character the user types isn't received by the textbox. Apparently .trigger is the way to go; here's what I've tried so far

```
self.editCell.trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {which: e.charCode}));
```

I tried passing more parameters like keyCode, charCode... etc without success.

So what would be the best way to pass the keystroke to the input control?

Comment: `trigger` only calls userland event handlers. It does not simulate the native event. Is there a reason you can't do `self.editCell.val(e.charCode)`?

Comment: That makes sense. Yeah.. for some reason I was stuck with that idea, I need to pass the event to the input. Just did it with .val() and it works beautifully. I feel stupid now, thanks :P

Comment: I still would like to know if it's possible to pass an event or simulate keystrokes though, just for personal knowledge. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only behavior that you are changing is that you want to navigate between other cells with the arrow keys, correct?

Instead of whitelisting actions, why don't you just let the native code handle the heavy lifting and only detect the usage of the arrow keys?

something like:

```
function cellKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.keyCode > 36 && e.keyCode < 40) {
        // select a new cell
    }
}
```